# How to use the Media Button (buttons on headphones) to run the method which is in the onClickListener?

Tags: android, android-studio

As in the topic, I want to start the method when I press the button on the headphones. There are a lot of such topics, but none does raise the problem when the method is in the onClickListener. I have tried many solutions, but I can not find the right one.

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.bartek.przyciskidosluchawek.MainActivity">

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20">

    <Button
        android:text="@string/but1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/but_niebieski"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:contentDescription="@string/but1"
        android:onClick="klik_niebieski" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/but2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/but_czerwony"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:onClick="klik_czerwony" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/but3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/but_zolty"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:onClick="klik_zolty" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5">

    <Button
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_zmiana" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My MainActivity:

```
package com.example.bartek.przyciskidosluchawek;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button but_nieb;
private Button but_czerw;
private Button but_zolt;
private Button but_zmiana;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    but_nieb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but_niebieski);
    but_czerw = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but_czerwony);
    but_zolt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but_zolty);
    but_zmiana = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_zmiana);


    but_nieb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            but_zmiana.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });
    but_czerw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            but_zmiana.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });
    but_zolt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            but_zmiana.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

This is a simple application, because I care about the method in the onClickListener and use the buttons on the headphones, and she perfectly illustrates my problem.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a BroadcastReceiver with the Intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
</intent-filter>
```

and then process those Intents to get the actual button press. Alternatively you could take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html for a more complete guide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though, I still have a problem calling a method from another class placed in the onClickListener. How to call it in another class?